# How to warm up Azure App Service in staging slot and then swap with production when using virtual directories

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure app service with a staging slot. I have setup both to use virtual directories to include a number of websites. The folders are client, server and legacy. I have setup custom domains on both production and the staging slot.

The custom domains for the production slot are

- client.sitename.com
- server.sitename.com
- legacy.sitename.com

The custom domains for the staging slot are

- clientstaging.sitename.com
- serverstaging.sitename.com
- legacystaging.sitename.com

I've updated the app service to include a web.config file to handle navigating requests to the correct directory and also run some code to warm up the applications. When the warm up code completes emails are sent which contain environment variables so I can tell which environment has been warmed up. The variables are in the projects themselves so are not connected to the variables on the app service.

The web.config of the current production slot contains the following

```
<applicationInitialization doAppInitAfterRestart="true" skipManagedModules="false">
    <add initializationPage="/primes/warmup" hostName="client.sitename.com" /> 
    <add initializationPage="/api/v1/primes/warmup?token=tokenId" hostName="server.sitename.com"/>
    <add initializationPage="/?initialise" hostName="legacy.sitename.com"/>      
</applicationInitialization>
```

The web.config of the current staging slot contains the following

```
<applicationInitialization doAppInitAfterRestart="true" skipManagedModules="false">
    <add initializationPage="/primes/warmup" hostName="clientstaging.sitename.com" /> 
    <add initializationPage="/api/v1/primes/warmup?token=tokenId" hostName="serverstaging.sitename.com"/>
    <add initializationPage="/?initialise" hostName="legacystaging.sitename.com"/>      
</applicationInitialization>
```

This works until the slots are swapped. If I restart the production slot after the slot I am receiving emails with the variables coming from the staging slot. The web.config on production now has hostNames with 'staging' and the staging slot looks to be warmed up rather than the production slot.

The production slot of the app service recycles sometimes so the applicationInitialization should be triggered and warm up that slot when it happens.

Is there a way of setting up the applicationInitialization so that it can work for both slots?

Comment: Hi Tom, Just wanted to clarify is there a specific requirement where you wish to warm up both the slots? We usually warm up staging slot before swapping it to production.

Comment: Hi Dashleen. I only want to warm up the staging slot before swapping. I have a task that sends emails to notify me of when the warm up tasks have been completed and I seem to be receiving them from both staging and production. According to the documentation I should only be getting them from staging. I don't want to warm up production. The last test I ran I restarted the app on staging and got 1 email as expected. When I swapped the slots I got 2 email where I was expecting just 1 from the production slot when it was swapped to staging